# Xamarin.Android: How to Get an Icon

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-resources

I'm trying to get an `Android.Graphics.Drawables.Icon` but unsure of how to do so.

I've got this code:

```
Icon icon = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.tab_subs);
```

I'm not able to do this, because of exception:

Cannot implicitly convert type `Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable` to `Android.Graphics.Drawables.Icon`

I've tried casting into an `Icon`, no dice:

`Android.Graphics.Drawables.Icon icon = (Icon)Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.tab_subs);`

To make matters worse, `Resources.GetDrawable(int)` is obsolete: 'deprecated'

...and resource `tab_subs` is available in other contexts.  For some reason, the  resource is not available in the context of `MainActivity`

https://github.com/hexag0d/BitChute_Mobile_Android_BottomNav/blob/AppSettingsAdder/MainActivity.cs

Does anyone know how to get an `Icon` in xamarin.android ?

Here is the `Resource` file:

https://github.com/hexag0d/BitChute_Mobile_Android_BottomNav/blob/AppSettingsAdder/Resources/drawable/tab_subs.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're after?

```
Icon icon = Icon.CreateWithResource(this, Resource.Drawable.tab_subs);
```

More information and other ways to load an Icon are documented here...
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Icon#public-methods_1